# How to retrieve following json string to separate objects in c#

Tags: c#, json

```
hotel_pricesURL = string_builder.ToString();               
RootobjectOne robjectOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectOne>(hotel_pricesURL);
List<OneStar> one_star_list = new List<OneStar>();
var check = robjectOne.onestar;
foreach(var items in check)
{

}
```

Including `RootobjectOne` class:

```
    public class RootobjectOne
    {
        [JsonProperty("OneStar")]
        public OneStar onestar { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("TwoStar")]
        public TwoStar twostar { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ThreeStar")]
        public ThreeStar threestar { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("FourStar")]
        public FourStar fourstar { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("FiveStar")]
        public FiveStar fivestar { get; set; }


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)this;
        }

    }
    public class OneStar
    {
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)this;
        }


        [JsonProperty("median")]
        public string median { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lowest")]
        public string lowest { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string value { get; set; }
        //public string 
    }


  **this is the response from the web service**

 {
     "5 star": {
      "median": "134.04",
      "lowest": "83.57",
      "value": "134.04"
     },
     "1 star": {
      "median": "28.86",
      "lowest": "28.86",
      "value": "28.86"
     },
     "4 star": {
      "median": "76.35",
      "lowest": "36.71",
      "value": "76.35"
     },
     "2 star": {
      "median": "24.78",
      "lowest": "20.42",
      "value": "24.78"
     },
     "3 star": {
      "median": "37.65",
      "lowest": "20.33",
      "value": "37.65"
     }
    }
```

I am getting an error stating

> Unable to cast object of type 'OneStar' to type'System.Collections.IEnumerator'

Why? And how do I solve this?

Comment: i am getting  this error in the foreach loop at the break point,  and this action results drag towards GetEnumerator() method

Comment: please provide a [mcve] - what is robjectOne?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your `RootobjectOne` class?

Comment: Without you JSON it's hard to tell, but apparently `onestar` is not enumerable (List, IEnumerable, etc.)

Comment: Hi !  Henrik Ilgen i have add the RootobjectOne class , please refer the  code below

Comment: OneStar is not inheriting IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, your class is implementing, but not inheriting the IEnumerable interface, so it is still not seen as a collection.

Second, even if you inherit it, you have no collections in OneStar and nothing to enumerate.

Third, all those Json flags are not necessary as you are just redefining the defaults that are already set.

**Solution**

You need an additional "wrapper" class that is your collection, or just omit your custom implementation of an enumerable collection (as it does not appear from your code that you need it) and just define the property that contains the class as a collection:

```
public class RootobjectOne
{
    public List<OneStar> onestar { get; set; }
    public List<TwoStar> twostar { get; set; }
    public List<ThreeStar> threestar { get; set; }
    public List<FourStar> fourstar { get; set; }
    public List<FiveStar> fivestar { get; set; }
}
```